# Importlib.import_module will not import the module even though the param is the abs path

Tags: python, import, module

I have my `.py` module which is in `C:\Python_Projects\MyModules\` with the name `button_generator.py`.

My code goes something like this:

```
module_path='C:\\Python_Projects\\MyModules'
module_name='button_generator.py'
sys.path.append(module_path)
try:
   limp=importlib.import_module(module_name.split('.')[0])
except:
   print 'module import error'
```

I have tried other versions aswell:

- importlib.import_module(module_name) without the split
- importlib.import_module('C:\Python_Projects\MyModules\button_generator.py')
- importlib.import_module('C:\Python_Projects\MyModules\button_generator')

The folder `C:\Python_Projects\MyModules` is in my sys.path as I checked during debug.

Why wouldn't the module import?

Comment: What if you just do `import button_generator`? Also if you catch the exception rather than throwing it away, what does it say?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest you to reorder your project directories and avoid calling other modules which are not in your current directory project. You'll avoid those kind of errors.

For example, let's organize our project directories and folders to look something like this:

```
MyProjectFolder/
├── main.py
└── modules
    ├── __init__.py
    └── MyLib.py
```

**NB:** Don't forget to add an empty file called `__init__.py`

**MyLib.py :**

```
#!/usr/bin/python3

class MyLib:
    def __init__(self):
        self.say_hello = "Hello i'm in modules/MyLib"

    def print_say_hello(self):
        print(self.say_hello)
```

**main.py:**

```
#!/usr/bin/python3

# from folder.file import class
from modules.MyLib import MyLib

class MainClass:
    def __init__(self):
        my_lib = MyLib()           # load MyLib class
        my_lib.print_say_hello()   # access to MyLib methods

### Test
if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = MainClass()
```

**In terminal when i run:**

```
$ python3 main.py
```

**output:**

```
Hello i'm in modules/MyLib
```

So here we have successfully imported the class in `modules/MyLib.py` into our `main.py` file.

Answer (score 1):

I found the error:

After treating the ImportError exception by printing it's args, I noticed that `button_generator.py` had an Import that was not resolving. Basically, `button_generator.py` could not be imported because it had a wrong import.

Comment: Great for you !